# Values Entered in column(Input Text) of af:table not propagating to Managed bean

Tags: oracle-adf, managed-bean

I am facing a problem in my adf application. I am having an af:table component on page which is drag-drop from the data control in the edit Mode. In that I am editing the column values with new values, let us say I changed the value of first column and moved to second column in between I am calling a method in the Managed bean on blur of the first column (for post-text-query(oracle forms)). In Managed bean when I try to access the value of the first column I am not getting the new value entered only old value is coming, I have two questions

1. When I tried with `autosubmit=true` on the column and moved focus from that row(column) to any other row or component and come back to perform blur operation, then value is available in the managed bean.
2. Also I tried to access values by creating bindings to the inputtext (in table column) and mapping them with managed bean fails, unlike normal input text.

Could any one explain whats happening in both the cases and also the way of accessing the values in managed bean in my case (getting the value immediately in Managedbean).

Answer (score 0):

I would try a `valueChangeListener` and get the user new value from `getNewValue()` method of the event.

1/ `autoSubmit=true` updates the model as soon as the user leaves the inputText.